# Zend Framework Router dynamic routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-controller-router

I bumped into a problem and I can't seem to find a good solution to make it work. I have to make some dynamic routes into a Zend Framework project. I'll explain shortly what my problem is:

I need to have dynamic custom routes that "extend" the default route (`module/controller/action/params`). The project I'm working for has several partners and the routes have to work with those.
To store the partners I've made a static class and it looks like this.

```
<?php
    class App_Partner
    {
        static public $partners = array(
            array(
                'name' => 'partner1',
                'picture' => 'partner1.jpg'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'partner2',
                'picture' => 'partner2.jpg'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'partner3',
                'picture' => 'partner3.jpg'
            )
        );
        static public function routePartners() {
            $partners = array();

            foreach(self::$partners as $partner) {
                array_push($partners, strtolower($partner['name']));
            }
            $regex = '(' . implode('|', $partners) . ')';

            return $regex;
        }
    }
```

So `App_Partner::routePartners()` return me a string like `(partner1|partner2|partner3)` which I use to create the right routes. My goal is to have the custom routes for each partner for every route I have set in the Bootstrap. So if I have a route `add-product.html` set I want it to work for each partner as `partner1/add-product.html`, `partner2/add-product.html` and `partner3/add-product.html`.
Also, `partner1/`, `partner2/`, `partner3` should route to `default/index/index`.

In fact, I made this thing to work using routes like the one below.

```
<?php
$routeProposal = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    App_Partner::routePartners() . '?/?proposals.html',
    array(
        'module' => 'default',
        'controller' => 'proposal',
        'action' => 'index',
        'page' => 1
    ),
    array( 1 => 'partner'),
    "%s/proposals.html"
);
$router->addRoute('proposal', $routeProposal);
```

**The problem**

The above route works fine if I use a partner in the request URI, but if I don't, I get double slashes like `public//proposals.html` because of the reverse route set in the route above to be `"%s/proposals.html"`. I can't seem to find a way to avoid this reverse route because I build my urls using the **url view helper** and if the reverse route isn't set I get an exception stating this.

I also need the routes to work without a partner set, which will be the default way (`add-product.html`, `proposals.html` etc).

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626048/zend-framework-how-to-map-fully-dynamic-route

Comment: I read that but it doesn't help me too much. His routes are unique and different. Mine are "overridable" - several route have to have the same name so I can build urls with the URL helper based on the routes' name.

Comment: :-) His routes are my routes = same user. I have a solution, I'll write it up later if someone else doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't check out who posted the question :) Yeah, so my routes need to be the same, but overriden if I'm in the case where I have a partner set in the request URI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your description, it seems like you're looking for a [zend router chain](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.chain), where your *partner* is an optional chain.

Here's a similar question, but using a hostname route : [Zend Framework: get subdomain parameter from route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181282/zend-framework-get-subdomain-parameter-from-route/5182866#5182866). I adapted it to solve your problem, just put the following in your Bootstrap.php to initialize the routing :

```
protected function _initRoute()
{
    $this->bootstrap('FrontController');
    $router = $this->getResource('FrontController')->getRouter();

    // Default route
    $router->removeDefaultRoutes();
    $defaultRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
                    ':controller/:action/*',
                    array(
                        'module' => 'default',
                        'controller' => 'index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    )
    );
    $router->addRoute('default', $defaultRoute);

    $partnerRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        ':partner',
        array('partner' => 'none'),
        array('partner' => '^(partner1|partner2|partner3)$')
    );
    $router->addRoute('partner', $partnerRoute->chain($defaultRoute));
}
```

Change as you see fit. In your controllers you will only get a value for the partner parameter if it was actually specified AND valid (you will get a routing error if the partner doesn't exist)...

Answer (score 1):

I use a similar process to detech lang, in my route (but with a ini file).

You can use a default value for you partners parameter to make the route working without partner, and add a `?` to your regex.

But actually, I don't know how to avoid the double `//`...

Hope that helps.

EDIT: For your information, here is a simplified version of my route with language:

```
routes.lang.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.lang.route = "lang/:language/*"
routes.lang.reqs.language = "^(en|fr|nl|de)?$"
routes.lang.defaults.language = none
routes.lang.defaults.module = default
routes.lang.defaults.controller = index
routes.lang.defaults.action = language
```

Comment: The thing is I can't use a default string for the case where I have no partner. This approach, based on mandatory string inside the route works with the route I posted. The problem seems to be at the reversed route which URL view helper uses to build urls.